# Conversion between IEnumerable to IList (Dapper return result)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, dapper

There is signature of `UserManager` method (ASP .NET Identity Core default implementation):

```
public Task<IList<string>> GetRolesAsync(User user) {
    const string query = @"
                select r.[Name]
                  from [UserRoles] ur
             left join [Roles] r on r.RoleId = ur.RoleId
                 where ur.UserId = @userId;
    ";

    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
            return connection.Query<string>(query, new { userId = user.UserId });
    });
}
```

But unfortunately `Dapper.Query<T>` returns `IEnumerable<T>`.

Is it possible to return `IList<T>` or i have to make conversion myself?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try to use an **explicit** cast

```
return (IList<string>)connection.Query<string>(query, new { userId = user.UserId });
```

Comment: @FSou1 I am one of the main authors and I disagree ;)

Comment: There is no guarantee that your cast will always work.  This could easily throw an exception.  ToList is safer.

Answer (score 19):

Dapper only guarantees to hand you an `IEnumerable<T>`. So you should only assume that. In particular, it already has different scenarios where it can give you **either** a populated list, **or** a deferred iterator.

The simplest approach is to just call `.ToList()`. If you are intent on avoiding an alloc, then maybe do a speculative test:

```
static IList<T> SpeculativeToList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    return source as IList<T> ?? source.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Given that the `IEnumberable<T>` does not guarantee its item's order,  does this mean that the Dapper result (I use `QueryAsync<T>`), where one use an "order by" in the sql query, is not guaranteed either? -- And if not, how does one achieve that? -- Will an immediate call using e.g. `ToList()` fix that?

Comment: @Asons `IEnumerable<T>` respects order; if you specify an ORDER BY in your query, it will absolutely be retained. What are you referring to, about "does not guarantee its item's order"? I think you're misinterpreting something. For example, it is true to say that many ORMs (just like many databases) don't say anything about order ***if you haven't specified one***, but that's a very different statement

Comment: First off, thank you for a quick response, and for all the work you put in Dapper. -- Second, being a self-taught coder I off and on miss out on the "code behind stuff" and gets unsure when I know I lack more deeper knowledge of how things works, and _am now sure I misinterpreted this post/answer :)_  https://stackoverflow.com/a/10409944/2827823

Comment: @Asons yep; in the case of hash-set (in that answer), it is hash-set itself that discards order and has no defined order; you can think of IEnumerable as a hose-pipe or conveyor belt (sort of): things will always come off in the same order that they're pushed in, but it does need the thing doing the pushing to care about order. Many things (most things): do indeed care about order. Some things just don't. But that's not the fault of the hose-pipe

Answer (score 2):

Just call `.ToList()` on it?

```
return connection.Query<string>(query, new { userId = user.UserId }).ToList();
```

This would enumerate the `IEnumerable<T>` and create an in-memory copy of all elements found as a `List<T>`.

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'List<string>>' to 'IList<string>>'

Comment: @FSou1: Are you sure that's the extent of the error and the overall issue?  A `List<string>` is implicitly convertible to an `IList<string>`.  For example, this works:  `IList<string> Test() { return new List<string>(); }`

Comment: Yeah, as i can see in my error list and any manipulations. Implicity convert works as expected correct.