# Custom Sort Extenstion

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to implement custom sorting for a functionality that goes like the below:
A list of users (First Middle Last name combination)where middle name is optional.
Here are a few criterias that I have for sorting:

1-first,middle,last

2-first,last,middle

3-last,middle,first

4-last,first,middle

I tried using linq's **orderby** followed by **then** but it wont work that way coz as i get the list of users ,i am converting the list of users to **IEnumerable** & pass this to the view to bind it to dropdownlist.
Here is my final list assigned to the viewmodal:

```
 viewModel.Users= users
                     .Select(usr=> new SelectListItem()
                     {
                         Text = $"{usr.FirstName} {usr.MiddleName} {usr.LastName}",
                         Value = $"{usr.FirstName} {usr.MiddleName} {usr.LastName}"
                     }).ToArray();
```

So the question is how do i sort IEnumerable items based on the above criteria?

I am aware that this wont work with the existing sorting & I need some help in custom sorting i.e. more of creating an extension method that will be able to sort based on the above critera.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: I find it a little unclear what you are asking. Maybe an actual example input and output

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand your question You don't need custom sorting for that. You can easily sort IEnumerable like this.

1-first,middle,last

```
users.OrderBy(item => item.Firstname).ThenBy(item => item.Midname).ThenBy(item => item.Lastname);
```

2-first,last,middle

```
users.OrderBy(item => item.Firstname).ThenBy(item => item.Lastname).ThenBy(item => item.Midname);
```

3-last,middle,first

```
users.OrderBy(item => item.Lastname).ThenBy(item => item.Midname).ThenBy(item => item.Firstname);
```

4-last,first,middle

```
users.OrderBy(item => item.Lastname).ThenBy(item => item.Firstname).ThenBy(item => item.Midname);
```

Comment: I think the answer is mostly correct but I think that he want the user to be able to select the sorting, so I would add a switch or a if to allow this

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. As i mentioned it in the question, i did used order & then of linq to achieve this but there is a slight confusion that i have which might be silly but i have to ask it anyway. This sorting will persist if i convert it into selectitem lists?

Comment: @user15532895 IEnumerable/IEnumerable<T> makes no guarantees about ordering. It depends on implementation behind that interface. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10409944/5964792). So I suggest you use List insted of IEnumerable. If you convert your IEnumerable to List you can also use Sort method with custom IComparer